# C++ typedef to rename functions

Tags: c++, function, templates, typedef, template-meta-programming

I would like to be able to `typedef` functions in order to be able to use template metaprogramming as a function selector (like in the example below). I've also tried passing the function as a template argument. In both cases the error arises because the functions are not `types`. I know either of these methods would work if they were functors, but I'd like to be able to have a general solution.

Is there an actual way to "`typedef` functions", but under a different name, that I'm just not aware of?

EDIT:

My use case at this time is that I would like to be able to select between using `boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml` and `boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json` . But it is not limited to just this case, and using member functions, function pointers or `std::function` will require all of the exact function defintions to be found and copied to *correctly* create a selector.

A more general way to describe the use case would be like using `typedef double my_float` so that at a later time all of the code can be changed with a single edit. Or, more advanced, the `typedef` could be defined in a metaprogam selector.

```
void foo1() { /*do stuff*/ }
void foo2() { /*do other stuff*/ }

template <bool SELECT>
struct Selector {
    typedef foo1 foo;
};

template <>
struct Selector<false> {
    typedef foo2 foo;
};
```

Comment: If I'm understanding what you want to do, just have a member function that calls it.

Comment: You might want to look into std::function and std::bind, as I don't think you're actually looking for a typedef / type alias here.

Comment: @chris That would require the member function have a matching type signature. For some of the heavily templated/overloaded function in boost/STL that would be very difficult to get right.

Comment: @JohnSmith, Ok I guess I missed the point then.

Comment: A `typedef` would require a function to be a type, which it isn't - just like `2` and `"foo"` are not types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yet another couple of solutions:

#### 1) C++03 solution: constant static function pointer as a member of a class template

```
typedef void (*Foo)();

template <bool>
struct Selector
{
    static const Foo foo;
};

template <bool select>
const Foo Selector<select>::foo = foo1;

template <>
const Foo Selector<false>::foo = foo2;

// ...

Selector<true>::foo();
Selector<false>::foo();
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6ad18b1070de3a2)

#### 2) C++11 solution: constant static `auto` member of a class template

```
template <bool>
struct Selector
{
    static constexpr auto foo = foo1;
};

template <>
struct Selector<false>
{
    static constexpr auto foo = foo2;
};

// ...

Selector<true>::foo();
Selector<false>::foo();
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f20271c3a3e43de)

#### 3) C++14 solution: `auto` variable template

```
template <bool>
constexpr auto foo = nullptr;

template <>
constexpr auto foo<true> = foo1;

template <>
constexpr auto foo<false> = foo2;

// ...

foo<true>();
foo<false>();
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/962173bd39d4f85c)

Comment: The `C++14` example words perfectly. Note that it also worked for me with `Clang 3.4 -std=c++11`.

Comment: Works only because both foo1 and foo2 have the same signature. To use foo you have to know what parameters you have to pass

Comment: @JohnSmith It [doesn't work with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` flags](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6ad18b1070de3a2), of course.

Comment: @MassimoCosta As I can see all other solutions here have the same disadvantage.

Comment: Yes, but John Smith said this is the problem!

Comment: @Constructor Actually `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++11` produces no errors or warnings for me.

Comment: @MassimoCosta Where did he say that?

Comment: @JohnSmith Then your version of clang has a bug because variable templates is not a C++11 feature.

Comment: @MassimoCosta No, this works if for example you have `void foo1(double);` and `int foo2(int)`.

Comment: @Constructor Same story with `gcc 4.9`...   I don't actually see any variable templates here, though.

Comment: Ok, I understood the problem was also the _number_ of parameters not only the type

Comment: @JohnSmith `foo` is a variable template here.

Comment: @Constructor Oh wait, I see the difference. I wrote this in a hurry and didn't really pay attention to the fact that I was doing it differently: `void foo(double d) {}` `int foo2(int x) {return 1;}` `template <bool T>` `struct FOB { static constexpr auto f = foo; };` `template<>` `struct FOB<false> { static constexpr auto f = foo2; };`

Comment: @MassimoCosta Sorry about the confusion, I was trying to imply all posibilities by mentioning overloads.

Comment: @JohnSmith `static auto` class members is a C++11 feature so your compilers are right when accept such code.

Comment: @Constructor Great! Thanks. Do you mind adding that option to your answer to support `C++11` people?

Comment: Apparently this does not infact work with overloaded functions :(

Comment: @JohnSmith You can [use `static_cast` to get the needed function overload](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2f1007a571139de) (C++11). Or [declare template class member of the proper type](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86a278b7fb1a13d9) (C++03).

Answer (score 3):

I assume your goal is just to select the function based on some `bool`. You can easily do this with member functions:

```
template <bool select>
struct selector {
    void operator () () {foo1();}
};

template <>
struct selector <false> {
    void operator () () {foo2();}
};
```

You can of course use an `int` parameter and the same technique to switch between more than two functions. You can then pass this `struct` as argument to any function that expects a function of the same signature as `foo1`. [(Live)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/625c84f4625e3461)

Comment: Thanks, this would work. As I mentioned in the comments about, the problem is with some of the heavily overloaded Boost/STL functions

Answer (score 2):

You can :

**1)** Use member functions

```
void foo1() { std::cout << "foo1\n"; }
void foo2() { std::cout << "foo2\n"; }

template <bool SELECT>
struct Selector {
    void foo() { foo1(); };
};

template <>
struct Selector<false> {
    void foo() { foo2(); };
};

int main() {

  Selector<true> s1t;
  Selector<false> s1f;

  s1t.foo();
  s1f.foo();
}
```

**2)** Use a generic function wrapper such as `std::function` :

```
void foo1() { std::cout << "foo1\n"; }
void foo2() { std::cout << "foo2\n"; }

template <bool SELECT>
struct Selector2 {
    std::function<void(void)> foo = foo1;
};

template <>
struct Selector2<false> {
    std::function<void(void)> foo = foo2;
};

int main() {

  Selector2<true> s2t;
  Selector2<false> s2f;

  s2t.foo();
  s2f.foo();

  return 0;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e8dad3e68b9f3dc)**

Comment: Thanks, this would work. As I mentioned in the comments about, the problem is with some of the heavily overloaded Boost/STL functions.

Comment: What means "the problem is with some of the heavily overloaded Boost/STL functions" ?. IMHO the `std::function` solution is very elegant and flexible. You should anyway have a fixed (or minimal using default values) signature of a function to call it.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/property_tree/reference.html#header.boost.property_tree.xml_parser_hpp

read_xml is an example. It only has two overloads, but quite a few number of arguments. `std::function` or a member function would have to have the correct function signatures to correctly map these.

Comment: Please, add an example of what you need! To call a function you must know the signature to pass parameters. or you need a generic map (like Qt QVariantMap class)

Comment: @JohnSmith I agree with MassimoCosta : you should respecify your question by editing it, probably with more code and use cases, to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: @MassimoCosta @quantdev, I'll do that; but my point was that there is no *one* use case. Today I want to rename `read_xml`, but tomorrow it may be something else. Each time would require finding and re-writing the exact function definitions; and since I consider my time valuable I do not want to do that.

Comment: Also our time is valuable but anyway we can help you. The problem is that I don't understand how do you think to solve the problem of **function call**. If you don't know what is the signature of the function you're calling how do you know how to pass parameters to it?

Comment: @MassimoCosta Let's say I want to select `log_foo` from between `std::log10` and `std::log` which should be passed a `typedef int log_t` but in some places I want to use `typdef long long log_t`. Now I need to have four function definitions in the selector. Add a third `typedef` and this becomes nine.

Comment: In this case you know you have only one parameter. So you can use the "auto" solution